# How to show $\phi\textbf{U}\psi\equiv\psi\textbf{R}(\phi\lor\psi)\land\textbf{F}\psi$ using semantic equivalences.

Tags: proof-verification, logic

I don't know how to show

$$\phi\,\textbf{U}\,\psi\equiv\psi\,\textbf{R}\,(\phi\lor\psi)\land\textbf{F}\psi$$

using semantic equivalences.

Can someone provide some suggestions?

$\textbf{U}$ denotes for "Until"

$\textbf{R}$ denotes for "Release"

$\textbf{F}$ denotes for "Future"

For more details about linear temporal logic and the meaning of the temporal operators $\textbf{U}$, $\textbf{R}$ and $\textbf{F}$, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic).

Comment: What ard: U,R,F ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I've added it.

Comment: Can you explain those predicates a bit more? E.g. $\phi U \psi$ means ... '$\phi$ until $\psi$' ...? ... so $\phi$ is true until $\psi$ is true ... but once $\psi$ is true $\phi$ is no longer true? Or unknown? Or ...? And the $R$ and $F$ predicates I can't make any intuitive sense of at all ...

Comment: It's unknown. And The connectives X,F,G,U,R, and W are temporal connectives.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to give a precise answer to this question if we do not know which semantic equivalences are allowed to be used.

A possible proof of the equivalence is by means of the temporal operator $\textbf{W}$ (*unless* or *weak until*): $\phi \, \textbf{W} \, \psi$  means that $\phi$ remains true until $\psi$ becomes true, but does not require that $\psi$ ever does become true; in other words, $\phi \, \textbf{W} \, \psi \equiv (\phi \,\textbf{U}\, \psi) ∨ \textbf{G}\phi \equiv \psi \,\textbf{R}\, (\psi ∨ \phi)$. (For a formal proof of the equivalence $\phi \, \textbf{W} \, \psi \equiv \psi \,\textbf{R}\, (\psi ∨ \phi)$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586508/how-to-show-phi-textbfw-psi-equiv-psi-textbfr-phi-lor-psi-from-definiti/2586740#2586740)). So,

$\phi \,\textbf{U}\, \psi ≡ \textbf{F} \psi ∧ (\phi \, \textbf{W} \, \psi)  ≡ \textbf{F} \psi ∧ (\psi \,\textbf{R}\, (\psi ∨ \phi))$.