# How to show $\phi\textbf{W}\psi\equiv\psi\textbf{R}(\phi\lor\psi)$ from definitions.

Tags: proof-verification, logic

I'd like to show  $\phi\,\textbf{W}\,\psi\equiv\psi\,\textbf{R}\,(\phi\lor\psi)$ from definitions.

- $\phi\textbf{W}\psi\to\psi\textbf{R}(\phi\lor\psi).$ Suppose $\pi\vDash\phi\textbf{W}\psi$. Then there are two conditions:

  (a) Either there is some $i\ge 0$ such that $\pi^i\vDash\psi$ and for all $0\le j< i$ we have $\pi^j\vDash\phi$;

  (b) or for all $k\ge0$ we have $\pi^k\vDash\phi$.

  In case (a), there is a minimal such $i$, say $i_0$, and so $\pi^{i_0}\vDash\psi$ and, for all $0 \le j < i_0,$ $\pi^j\nvDash\psi$ and $\pi^j\vDash\phi$, hence $\pi\vDash\psi\textbf{R}(\phi\lor\psi).$

  In case (b), $\pi^k\vDash\phi$ for all $k\ge0$, hence $\pi\vDash\psi\textbf{R}(\phi\lor\psi).$

  Therefore, we have proved that in both case (a) and case (b), $\pi\vDash\psi\textbf{R}(\phi\lor\psi).$
- $\phi\textbf{W}\psi\leftarrow\psi\textbf{R}(\phi\lor\psi).$ Suppose $\pi\vDash\psi\textbf{R}(\phi\lor\psi)$. Then there are two conditions:

  (a) Either there is some $i\ge0$ such that $\pi^i\vDash\psi$ and for all $0\le j\le i$ we have $\pi^i\vDash\phi\lor\psi$;

  (b) or for all $k\ge0$ we have $\pi^k\vDash\phi\lor\psi$

  In case (a), there is a minimal such $i$, say $i_0$, and so $\pi^{i_0}\vDash\psi$ and, for all $0\le j< i_0$, $\pi^j\nvDash\psi$ and $\pi^j\vDash\phi$; in particular, $\pi^0\vDash\phi$ i.e. $\pi\vDash\phi$, hence $\pi\vDash\phi\textbf W\psi.$

  In case (b), either $\pi^k\vDash\phi$ for all $k\ge0$, and hence $\pi\vDash\phi\textbf{W}\psi$; or there is $h\ge0$ such that $\pi^h\nvDash\phi$ and $\pi^h\vDash\psi$, hence there is a minimal such $h$, say $h_0$, and so $\pi^i\vDash\phi$ for all $0\le i<h_0$, thus $\pi\vDash \phi\textbf{W}\psi.$

  Therefore, we have proved that in both case (a) and case (b), $\pi\vDash \phi\textbf{W}\psi.$

For more details about linear temporal logic and the meaning of the temporal operators $\textbf{U}$, $\textbf{R}$ and $\textbf{F}$, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic).

Comment: What are $\pi ^i$? What is $W$? What is $R$?  You say 'from definitions' ... ok, so what are those definitions?

Comment: Let $\pi = s_0\to s_1\to\cdots$ be a path in a model $\mathcal M = (S,\to,L)$. The $i$-suﬃx $\pi^i$ is the suﬃx $s_i\to s_{i+1}\to\dots$ of $\pi$.

Comment: Informally, **X** means “neXt state,” **F** means “some Future state,” **G** means “all future states (Globally),” **U** means “Until,” **R** means “Release,” and **W** means “Weak-until.”

Comment: $\phi\textbf W\psi$ is true if $\phi \textbf U \psi$ or $\phi$ is always true;
▸ Note that $\phi\textbf W\psi$ does not require $\psi$ to be true in the future.

Comment: $\phi\textbf R\psi$ is true if $\psi$ is true until inclusively $\phi$ releases $\psi$, or $\psi$ is always true.

▸ Note that $\phi\textbf R\psi$ does not require $\phi$ to be true in the future.

Comment: Edit the question to add the clarifications rather than use comments which can be removed without notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any two formulas $\varphi$ and $\chi$, $\varphi \,\textbf{R}\, \chi$ means that $\chi$ has to be true until and including the point where $\varphi$ first becomes true; if $\varphi$ never becomes true, $\chi$ must remain true forever (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic)).

Formally, suppose $\pi\vDash\psi \,\textbf{R}\, (\phi\lor\psi)$. Then,

1. either $\pi^j \models \phi \lor \psi$ for all $j \geq 0$,
2. or there exists $k \geq 0$ such that $\pi^k \models \psi$ and, for all $0 \leq i \leq k$, $\pi^i \models \phi \lor \psi$.

In case 1, either $\pi^j \models \phi$ for all $j \geq 0$, and hence $\pi \models \phi \,\textbf{W}\, \psi$; or there is $h \geq 0$ such that $\pi^{h} \not\models \phi$ and $\pi^{h} \models \psi$, hence there is a *minimal* such $h$, say $h_0$, and so $\pi^{i} \models \phi$ for all $0 \leq i < h_0$, thus $\pi \models \phi \,\textbf{W}\, \psi$.

In case 2, there is a *minimal* such $k$, say $k_0$, and so $\pi^{k_0} \models \psi$ and, for all $0 \leq i \leq k_0$, $\pi^i \not\models \psi$ and $\pi^i \models \phi$; hence $\pi \models \phi \,\textbf{W}\, \psi$, since $\pi^{k_0} \models \psi$ and, for all $0 \leq i < k_0$, and $\pi^i \models \phi$.

Therefore, we have proved that in both case 1 and case 2, $\pi \models \phi \,\textbf{W}\, \psi$.

Comment: What you want to say is $\varphi \textbf W\chi$?

Comment: And my question is $\phi\textbf{W}\psi\equiv\psi\textbf{R}(\phi\lor\psi)$ not $\phi\textbf{W}\psi\equiv\phi\textbf{R}(\phi\lor\psi)$

Comment: @walkcc - I edited my answer in order to be clearer (I hope so!).

Comment: I've already corrected the whole proof. Could you please double check it? Thanks!

Comment: I've corrected it. There are some typos in your answer. Like $\phi$ and $\psi$.

Comment: @walkcc - Oh yes, you're right. This also slightly simplifies the proof in on case, as you did correctly.